# Create a table in SQL Server based on a definition row in Excel WITHOUT using sampling

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I want to create a table in SQL Server and define the column names AND types in rows such as below - please READ ON after the picture. Like this:

[image]

I've already research and know of ways in which you just define COLUMNS in excel and under each column you give some sample values and SQL Server automatically creates a table with those columns, but the column types are "guessed" after sampling the first, let's say 100 rows (you can adjust the sampling size). This does ***NOT***  work for me. My table has a lot of variations (VarChar1, 2, 3, 5, or even CHAR). So I want to be able to define it using a description as shown above. Anyone has a solution? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my solution, first you need to import you definition into a table.

Then you can generate a script and execute it to create the table.

```
-- Sample Data in Temp Table #tt
CREATE TABLE #tt (
    fieldname VARCHAR(50)
    , datatype VARCHAR(50)
    )

INSERT INTO #tt
VALUES ('FirstName', 'varchar(20)'), ('LastName', 'varchar(20)'), ('Age', 'int')

-- Generate Script
DECLARE @sqlText VARCHAR(max) = (
        SELECT 'CREATE TABLE YourTableName (' + CHAR(13) + STUFF((
                    SELECT ', ' + fieldname + ' ' + datatype + '$$'
                    FROM #tt
                    --ORDER BY fieldname --commented out
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                    ), 1, 1, '') + ')'
        )

SET @sqlText = replace(@sqlText, '$$', CHAR(13))

PRINT @sqlText

-- Execute
EXEC (@sqlText)
```

In my example the generated script will be

```
CREATE TABLE YourTableName (
 Age int
, FirstName varchar(20)
, LastName varchar(20)
)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for the answer: never thought of this. The "insert" part threw me off, but now I am clear. I'll try this to see if it works. Thanks again

Comment: This works, Thanks again. Also, if you feel like this question is valuable, please vote it up and the reason is because questions with a score of ZERO do not even show up in search results, so people keep reasking them.

Comment: @LearnByReading, You're welcome. The question is interesting so I voted up.

Comment: This works perfectly; the only thing I changed was to comment out "fieldName" because this re-orders your original list of fields (which is what most would want). Now the original order is retained.